# Creating Cloud Tasks via Python - Custom parameters. New to development

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, cloud, google-cloud-tasks

EDIT* Adding code and more details of the process at the bottom:

I'm attempting a part of our development.

1. Queue must take the parameters period (int), etc and transform them into a Task. Some of these parameters have several keys and will need to be grouped.
2. The Queue must call the Task Service with the task and period
3. The Task Service takes must take the period and task and create an
   HTTP Target Task with the client library

We have cloud run setup with a Flask app for the API endpoints event/task. Those endpoints will verify the request and such. Specifically Task will handle receiving task from the Queue. We have a internal service as an embedded python module that received parameters and then uses them to execute an action. Once this service examines some data - it will then pass the parameters required for the Queue to take and transform to a task. I have some mock json payloads available as well.

I have the basic python to create a task in my sandbox queue - the next step I'd like to understand would be how to take the first received custom parameters and input them into the initial task creation. From there I'd like to know how to call the Task service with the new "task" parameter and the initial period in order to create the http target task. The actual json payload addition I think I have figured out but I'm having a heck of a time trying to wrap my head around this. We aren't using app engine.

Any input or pointers towards anything outside of GCPs docs would be awesome!

EDIT:

Alrighty - to elaborate:

I receive parameters. Some of these will have multiple properties. These parameters need to be used to create the overall Task and payload as shown in the below payload Json Schema for the HTTPS Task creation script. I'd like to combine these parameters to a "Task" and use "Task" and "Period" to create the actual task with the "Task" containing the other parameters for the JSON payload.

Code (sorry I know it's messy)

```
"""Create a task for a given queue with an arbitrary payload."""

import datetime
import json

from google.cloud import tasks_v2
from google.protobuf import duration_pb2, timestamp_pb2

#accept period,operation, event, resource parameters these will have multiple keys. This is based off the period int. 
period = int
operation = object
resource = str
event = object



#Config dict into Json payload for task assuming those prior parameters come as a dictionary
taskDict = {
    'operation' : object,
    'event' : object,
    'resource': str
}
app_json = json.dumps(taskDict)
Print (app_json)

#All below is creation of the HTTP target task
# Create a client.
client = tasks_v2.CloudTasksClient()

# TODO(developer): Uncomment these lines and replace with your values.
project = ''
queue = ''
location = ''
url = ''
payload = #jsonschema with period and Task (operation, event, resource)
in_seconds = 180
task_name = 'my-unique-task2'
deadline = 900

# Construct the fully qualified queue name.
parent = client.queue_path(project, location, queue)

# Construct the request body.
task = {
    "http_request": {  # Specify the type of request.
        "http_method": tasks_v2.HttpMethod.POST,
        "url": url,  # The full url path that the task will be sent to.
    }
}
if payload is not None:
    if isinstance(payload, dict):
        # Convert dict to JSON string
        payload = json.dumps(payload)
        # specify http content-type to application/json
        task["http_request"]["headers"] = {"Content-type": "application/json"}

    # The API expects a payload of type bytes.
    converted_payload = payload.encode()

    # Add the payload to the request.
    task["http_request"]["body"] = converted_payload

if in_seconds is not None:
    # Convert "seconds from now" into an rfc3339 datetime string.
    d = datetime.datetime.utcnow() + datetime.timedelta(seconds=in_seconds)

    # Create Timestamp protobuf.
    timestamp = timestamp_pb2.Timestamp()
    timestamp.FromDatetime(d)

    # Add the timestamp to the tasks.
    task["schedule_time"] = timestamp

if task_name is not None:
    # Add the name to tasks.
    task["name"] = client.task_path(project, location, queue, task_name)

if deadline is not None:
    # Add dispatch deadline for requests sent to the worker.
    duration = duration_pb2.Duration()
    task["dispatch_deadline"] = duration.FromSeconds(deadline)

# Use the client to build and send the task.
response = client.create_task(request={"parent": parent, "task": task})

print("Created task {}".format(response.name))
```

Schema for json

```
"title": "Task",
"description": "",
"type": "object",
"properties": {
    "event": {
        "type": "string"
    },
    "resource": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
            "type": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "resource_id": {
                "type": "number"
            },
            "project_id": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "zone": {
                "type": "string"
            }
        }
    },
    "operation": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
            "result_type": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "detail": {
                "type": "object"
            }
        }
    }
},
"required": ["event", "resource", "operation"]
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you include some code in your question that describes the challenge. Then we can provide answers as code to help. IIUC you're able to create tasks using Python code. Something is creating parameters that you now need to incorporate into the task creation. Without seeing code, it's difficult to provide an answer.

Comment: thank you - I tried to update - I will revise a bit more later

Comment: You've no need to apologize for "messy code", The code is fine and it much better explains what you want to do. Thank you for including it.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have more questions :-) But, I'll propose a naive solution (answer) and will add my questions there.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a naive solution. It simply wraps your existing code in a function. The function accepts the parameters that you describe it will need.

```py
import datetime
import json

from google.cloud import tasks_v2
from google.protobuf import duration_pb2, timestamp_pb2


def create_task(name:str, task:dict, period:int):
    client = tasks_v2.CloudTasksClient()

    project = ''
    location = ''
    queue = ''
    url = ''
    payload = task
    in_seconds = 180
    task_name = name
    deadline = 900

    parent = client.queue_path(project, location, queue)

    task = {
        "http_request": {
            "http_method": tasks_v2.HttpMethod.POST,
            "url": url,
        }
    }
    if payload is not None:
        if isinstance(payload, dict):
            payload = json.dumps(payload)
            task["http_request"]["headers"] = {"Content-type": "application/json"}

        converted_payload = payload.encode()
        task["http_request"]["body"] = converted_payload

    if in_seconds is not None:
        d = datetime.datetime.utcnow() + datetime.timedelta(seconds=in_seconds)
        timestamp = timestamp_pb2.Timestamp()
        timestamp.FromDatetime(d)
        task["schedule_time"] = timestamp

    if task_name is not None:
        task["name"] = client.task_path(project, location, queue, task_name)

    if deadline is not None:
        duration = duration_pb2.Duration()
        task["dispatch_deadline"] = duration.FromSeconds(deadline)

    response = client.create_task(request={"parent": parent, "task": task})
    return response.name


def main():
    name = ""
    task = {
        "event": "",
        "resource": {
            "type": "",
            "resource_id": 0,
            "project_id": "",
            "zone": "",
        },
        "operation": {
            "result_type": "",
            "detail": {},
        },
    }
    period = 500
    print(f"Created task {create_task(name, task, period)}")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

But there are issues with this approach:

1. There's no encapsulation of types or functionality, e.g. the `task` provided is an arbitrary dictionary without validation that it adheres to the (JSON) schema.
2. The Google Cloud Tasks client is created anew each time the function is invoked; it should likely be reused.
3. There's no error-handling.

Suggestions:

1. Create classes to represent your types (e.g. `Task`, `Resource`, `Operation`). You can then add types to your methods (e.g. `create_task(t: Task)`) and validate them (only valid `Tasks` can be used).

```py
class Operation:
    def __init__(self, result_type: str, detail:dict):
        self.result_type = result_type
        self.detail = detail
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.result_type}\n{self.detail}"

class Resource:
    def __init__(self, type:str, resource_id: int, project_id: str, zone: str):
        self.type = type
        self.resource_id = resource_id
        self.project_id = project_id
        self.zone = zone
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.type},{self.resource_id},{self.project_id}, {self.zone}"

class Task:
    def __init__(self, event:str, resource:Resource, operation:Operation):
        self.event = event
        self.resource = resource
        self.operation = operation
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.event}\nresource={self.resource}\noperation={self.operation}"


new_task = Task(
    event="",
    resource=Resource(
        type="",
        resource_id=5,
        project_id="",
        zone="",
    ),operation=Operation(
        result_type="",
        detail={
            "foo":"bar",
        }
    ),
)
print(new_task)
```

1. Create a class to represent Google Cloud Tasks client and methods (e.g. `create_task`). This way you can create a client once (for a given configuration: `project_id`, `location`, `queue` and then invoke `create_tasks` against it.
2. Rather than use Python dicts throughout your code, Google's client library adds types e.g. [CreateTaskRequest](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/cloudtasks/latest/google.cloud.tasks_v2.types.CreateTaskRequest). I encourage you to consider using these classes (for the same reasons as outlined above) in your code.

Questions:

1. There are tools that generate Python classes from JSON schema (e.g. [`python-jsonschema-objects`](https://github.com/cwacek/python-jsonschema-objects) -- I've not used this library). Your team should consider developing Python classes that represent the JSON schema(s) so that you need not reimplement these.

Comment: You're very welcome! I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks a ton!
Regarding your suggestions:

1) I need to clarify how these types are being defined. We have our 'Task' call response format roughly as :

{'resource': {'type': 'gce_instance', 'resource_id': 'our_id', 'project_id': 'my-project', 'zone': 'us-central1-a'}, 'operation': {'result_type': 'type.googleapis.com/error', 'detail': {'message': 'You cannot start an instance that does not have a boot disk.', 'code': 400, 'errors': [{'reason': 'invalidResourceUsage', 'message': 'You cannot start an instance that does not have a boot disk.', 'domain': 'global'}]}}, 'event': 'our.event'}

Comment: 2) You make a great point - I don't think I'd want a new client everytime!

3) Thank you - I'll dive through googles client library - as this should allow a bit better structure. I'll come back when I figure out exactly how our types are structured coming in and how they should be defined in classes/I write these out.

Comment: Let me add a very basic example of what I intend with my suggestion #1

Comment: Thanks so much! Upon review I've come accross a few tidbits of info

1) The client will be configured by the time it gets to this tool - with regards to the questions around creating a new one/reusing a created one

2) My owner mentioned to use dicts now as far as the python - but they're open to objects/class refinement as it develops. For the first case I'll define the parameters as classes and leave the client library for later !

Comment: Thanks for the updates. Using dicts is idiomatic for Python ("pythonic") so it's understandable to pursue this approach. Good luck!